# Mass renaming of files in folder

Tags: bash

I need to renami all the files below few files format in the folder in such a way that last `_2.txt` will be the same and `apac`, `emea`, `mds` will be the same in all files but before `_XXX_2.txt`  need to add `logs_date` to all the files.

```
ABC_xyz_123_apac_2.txt 
POR5_emea_2.txt
qw_1_0_122_mds_2.txt
```

to

```
logs_date_apac_2.txt
logs_date_emea_2.txt
logs_date_mds_2.txt
```

Comment: You should elaborate more on what you have tried - and if you haven't, what is the exact difficulty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but maybe this is what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *_2.txt;do
    # remove echo to rename the files once you check it does what you expect
    echo mv -v "$file" "$(sed 's/.*\(_.*_2\.txt\)$/logs_date\1/' <<<"$file")"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the help..
I have edited by Question, will the same script help ??

Comment: @Nirmal You can just try it out to see if it helps, it won't change anything unless you remove the `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use bash?

Bulk Rename Utility is an awesome tool that can easily rename multiple files in an intuitive way.

http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to or can't use sed, you can also try this, which might even run faster. No matter what solution you use, be sure to backup before if possible.

```
shopt +s extglob    # turn on the extglob shell option, which enables several extended pattern matching operators
set +H    # turn off ! style history substitution
for file in *_2.txt;do
    # remove echo to rename the files once you check it does what you expect
    echo mv -v "$file" "${file/?(*_)!(*apac*|*emea*|*mds*)_/logs_date_}"
done
```

${parameter/pattern/string} performs pattern substitution. First optionally a number of characters ending with an underscore are matched, then a following number of characters not containing apac, emea or mds and ending with an underscore are matched, then the match is replaced with "logs_date_".

Copied from the bash man page:

> ```
>           ?(pattern-list)
>                  Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
>           *(pattern-list)
>                  Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
>           +(pattern-list)
>                  Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
>           @(pattern-list)
>                  Matches one of the given patterns
>           !(pattern-list)
>                  Matches anything except one of the given patterns
> ```

Comment: Hi Ruby,
Is it possible for you to explain , how it works ?

Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped. I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mmv` command should be easy.

```
mmv '*_*_2.txt' 'logs_date_#2_2.txt' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the rename tool:

```
rename 's/.+(_[a-z]+_[0-9].)/logs_date$1/' files
```

This will give you the desired output.